# Trash moved to Other, wasn't removed

Tags: macos, catalina, storage, trash

I had 30 GB of trash (UnrealEngine4) and when I emptied it, it only took a second and it all became part of Other in About this Mac - Storage. I was looking at it, before it was 30GB in Trash, and then it all moved to Other.

I want to use Time Machine and I don't want 30GB of unusable trash. Can anybody help me remove it?

I'm using Catalina on a 2013 MacBook Pro.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)

Comment: Do you not want to wait the 24 hours for the snapshot to purge the space of it’s not needed for other files - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/332611/5472

Answer (score 0):

You should run an app like [DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com) and see if you can locate where the files in "other" are located. Then you can delete them directly.

Or if you can find where it's stored you can have Time Machine exclude it from the backup.